# Zend Form getValues() doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I'm trying to create simple form with Zend, I need to use this form in most part, so I create the default form then in controller i modify it for the occurrence with private function. But I have two problems:

1. the form getValues() doesn't take the value of text element.
2. I put render at the end of the form action, but it doesn't render to the right page.

The form consists of a text field and the sumbit button

Here is the code of my controller:

That is for customize the form

```
private function getSearchForm($action = '', $name, $type, $placeholder)
{
    $urlHelper = $this->_helper->getHelper('url');
    $this->_searchForm = new Application_Form_Admin_Search_Search();
    $this->_searchForm->setName($name);
    $text = $this->_searchForm->getElement('ricerca');
    $text->setLabel('Ricerca '.$type);
    $text->setName($type);
    $text->setAttrib('placeholder', $placeholder);
    $this->_searchForm->setAction($urlHelper->url(array(
        'controller' => 'admin',
        'action' => $action),
        'default'
    ));
    return $this->_searchForm;
}
```

there are the actions:

```
public function pneumaticoAction()
{
    $this->_searchForm = $this->getSearchForm('pneumaticosearch', 'search', 'pneumatico', 'Ricerca per: modello, marchio o codice');
    $this->view->searchForm = $this->_searchForm;
}

public function pneumaticosearchAction()
{
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'public');
    }
    $form=$this->_searchForm;
    if (!$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
        $this->render('pneumatico');
    }
    $values = $form->getValues();
    $this->view->assign(array(
        "pneumatici" => $this->_modelAdmin->searchPneumatici($values['pneumatico'])
    ));
    $this->render('pneumatico');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First question, whenever you get routed to `pneumaticosearch` action, you do not set `$this->_searchForm` but you have it as:

```
$form=$this->_searchForm;
```

Should be something like this:

```
$form = $this->getSearchForm('pneumaticosearch', 'search', 'pneumatico', 'Ricerca per: modello, marchio o codice');
```

And the second question. When you run render, it is similar to pass `$this->view` parameters to `.phtml`. I don't see your view files, but I guess you need to set view first:

```
$this->view->searchForm = $form
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the problem with $form->getValues() continues. If i render to view `$values` i get this result: `array ( 'ricerca' => '', )`. There isn't the value of text field. But if i render the `$_POST` i get this result `array ( 'pneumatico' => 'something', 'search' => 'Ricerca', )` that is what i need

Comment: then the question is: what are the names of each elements in your form?
In the code you just gave us, it seems there is an element which is called `ricerca`. Keys of the `$_POST` should be the same keys in your form in order to set any value in the form through `isValid`.

Comment: The form consists of a text field and the sumbit button: the text field name is `pneumatico` and the submit name is `search` as you can see on $_POST. These names i set on the private function that i post (`getSearchForm`). I can't understand why in the `$_POST` i get the right value and in the `getValues` no

Comment: To make sure that it's problem with form. You can check `$form->getElements()` to have all elements. You can double check it by `$form->populate($this->getRequest()->getPost())` to see if it can fix the `getValues` problem. I would suggest also to dump `$this->_getParams()`.

Comment: with `$form->getElements` I find all elements